# Why can't I attach to database files in SSMS that happen to be symbolic links?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a symbolic link for my .mdf and .ldf files which reside on a network drive. Now I'm trying to attach them to my Sql Server 2012 management studio but I'm getting following error:

[image]
Any thoughts?

Comment: Network *drive* or network *share*? The SQL Server account probably doesn't have a network *drive* mapped. (Even so, I'd be surprised if this scenario was actually supported; I think SQL Server wants/needs to know if a file is accessed through SMB or as a local file, though I must admit I've never tried it.) Note that, from 2008 R2 onwards, SQL Server supports storing databases on SMB shares directly, so you don't need symbolic links to get around restrictions on that.

Comment: yes, it is a network share. The symbolic link made it look like it was local and I see the .mdf file in the Attach process and I can select it but I get the error.

Comment: Try attaching the database directly from the UNC path to see if the problem is in the symbolic link or in the file access.

Comment: When I click Add under the Attach... option I only see my C drive

Comment: You don't need to be able to browse the network -- use [`CREATE DATABASE [name] ON (FILENAME = '\\path\file.mdf', FILENAME = '\\path\file.ldf') FOR ATTACH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms176061).

Comment: Well, good thing I linked to the correct syntax, as the above is wrong (should be `(FILENAME = ..), (FILENAME = ..)`).